# How do I run a module in another process/thread and use it's functions without blocking main script

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I was trying to be able to send/edit/delete messages and all that webhooks can't do (and i dont want to use them in this specific case).
I also wanted to see how to import some other module that's like looping in itself and blocking the entire script once i call the `run` function.
I don't know how I can run this in a multiprocess or thread. I mean yes I could start a process or thread with the `run` function.
But how am i supposed to call `send_msg` function afterwards? (or `edit_msg` and `delete_msg`, i didn't write them here since it will be similiar)

the bot.py:

```
import discord

def run(token):
    
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is ready.")

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        return #for now just trying to get the bot to send anything with the send_msg function from another process.

    client.run(token)


def send_msg(client, channel_id, text):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    if channel is None: return None
    
    try:
        msg = await channel.send(text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not send:", repr(e))
        return None
    else:
        return msg
```

I want to be able to use it like:

1. import this bot.py into main script
2. start the multiprocess/thread with the `run` function from main script
3. call `send_msg` from main script when i have a message to send (edit and delete are similiar so i only have to understand this)
4. get the return value from `send_msg` into main script and continue my way in main script without being blocked by the bot or anything (having to wait while sending/editing/deleting in the main script is okay, but I don't want to be blocked by the bot's async loop forever)

so is there any way to multiprocess/thread the entire module? or is there a solution to this? or maybe i should somehow make POST request myself instead of using discord.py (but I dont know how because of Gateways)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution to your problem, but I would start by dropping it into one class. At this point, I don't see you using the same client in "send_msg" function as you declared in "run" function. Also remember to add async before defining "send_msg" method.

```
import discord


def DiscordBot():
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = discord.Client()

    def run(token):

        @self.client.event
        async def on_ready():
            print("Bot is ready.")

        @self.client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.author == self.client.user:
                return

            return #for now just trying to get the bot to send anything with the send_msg function from another process.

        self.client.run(token)


    async def send_msg(self, channel_id, text):
        channel = self.client.get_channel(channel_id)
        if channel is None: return None
        
        try:
            msg = await channel.send(text)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not send:", repr(e))
            return None
        else:
            return msg
```